# generation of normally distributed random vector with covariance matrix

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

In matlab it is easy to generate a normally distributed random vector with a mean and a standard deviation. From the help randn:

Generate values from a normal distribution with mean 1 and standard
       deviation 2.
          r = 1 + 2.*randn(100,1);

Now I have a covariance matrix C and I want to generate N(0,C).

But how could I do this?

From the randn help:
Generate values from a bivariate normal distribution with specified mean
       vector and covariance matrix.
          mu = [1 2];
          Sigma = [1 .5; .5 2]; R = chol(Sigma);
          z = repmat(mu,100,1) + randn(100,2)*R;

But I don't know exactly what they are doing here.

Comment: Which part do you not understand?  `mu` is the mean vector (in your case 0, so leave it off), `Sigma` is the covariance matrix, and they're generating 100 pairs of random numbers.

Comment: I don't understand the repmat part. Is it also possible to do it this way: chol(C, 'lower') + randn(N,1); with C the covariance matrix

Comment: Sorry, I think I do understand now. The repmat is used to build a mean matrix for 100 pairs of random numbers.

Comment: you can use the MVNRND function from the Statistics Toolbox, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041866/gaussian-basis-function

Comment: @Donnie or Amro : you should post an answer so Derk can accept it and this question will be archived for anyone to consult :)

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat a math question, not a programming question. But I'm a big fan of writing great code that requires both solid math and programming knowledge, so I'll write this for posterity.

You need to take the Cholesky decomposition (or any decomposition/square root of a matrix) to generate correlated random variables from independent ones. This is because if `X` is a multivariate normal with mean `m` and covariance `D`, then `Y = AX` is a multivariate normal with mean `Am` and covariance matrix `ADA'` where `A'` is the transpose. If `D` is the identity matrix, then the covariance matrix is just `AA'` which you want to be equal to the covariance matrix `C` you are trying to generate.

The Cholesky decomposition computes such a matrix `A` and is the most efficient way to do it.

For more information, see: http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/viele/sta601s03/multnorm.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following built-in matlab function to do your job

```
mvnrnd(mu,SIGMA)
```